# Where is all the boot info located, I'd need to restore my OS? On which partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

[the only two questions that the system listed as similar are from before UEFI and GPT replaced the MBR way of doing things. If you think it is similar to other questions, please be so kind to point out HOW it's similar, and don't just say: "they're the same"]

Please review the attached image.
The C-drive has a Windows 10 install. On the D-drive is the original Win11, which I don't use. This is why it's first on the disk. However, I have to send this out for hardware repairs, possibly replacing the motherboard and the shops policy is to only treat reset systems. When I get it back, I want to restore my Win10 system.

See the image.

*My 1st question:*

I'm assuming it is the C-partition (with the status **Health, Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Basic Data Partition**) where all the necessary boot information is stored, *so that only thát partition needs to be backed-up in case anything goes wrong*?? If that's not so, then where is boot information stored? On one of the two hidden partitions, partition 1 and/or partition 5? I've backed up those 2 as well, but is that really necessary? My machine is a **Lenovo Legion 5 17ACH6H**

I only have space to back up one partition, about 130 GB. I think it should be just enough for the Win10 partition plus the restored Win11 partition, after it has been reset to default.

*My 2nd question:*

Assuming the reset configuration is *partition 1* then *C-drive* then
*partition 5*, can I just replace the two hidden partitions, and add the Win10 partition? Or is that too simplistic?

PS Why is the E-drive partition set as "active"? I haven't done that. What's the use or function of that, of making a partition "active"? Background: This is a partition with a Win7 installation, which doesn't boot anymore after it was moved from back-of-disk to front-of-disk.

[Screenshot of Disk configuration with 3 partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFKhz.jpg)

Comment: The ESP (EFI System Partition) holds the first stage boot.

Comment: Thanks for reacting, And where is the ESP located, in the attached image?

Comment: @GngrWtch - It's contained within the EFI partition.

Comment: "I'm assuming it is the C-partition (with the status Health, Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Basic Data Partition) where all the necessary boot information is stored, so that only thát partition needs to be backed-up in case anything goes wrong?" - You should backup the EFI, Recovery, and System partition.

Comment: It's the first partition on Disk0, the 260MB FAT32.

Comment: @ChanganAuto sorry, for  asking **And where is the ESP located, in the attached image**, that was a stupid question. I overlooked it in the image. My bad, also to Ramhound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C: partition contains your entire OS – the kernel, the Registry data, system libraries and services, program files, and even your account's files. This is the one you really need to back up if you want to restore Windows 10.

The "EFI System Partition" (which has no drive letter by default) contains the initial bootloader whose job is to start Windows. You should back it up, but it's not critical – it can be rebuilt using bcdboot.exe if needed.

Note that in Windows terminology (e.g. in your DiskMgmt screenshot), "Boot" indicates the partition holding *the entire OS* (i.e. C:\Windows), while "System" indicates the partition holding the early BIOS bootloader stages – which is the **exact opposite** of widespread terminology in other operating systems, where "system" would refer to the OS partition while "boot" would refer to the early bootloader.

In addition, a pointer to a specific file within the "EFI System Partition" is stored in your motherboard's NVRAM as an "EFI variable". The system should still be able to boot without it, though – if the NVRAM boot entry is missing, it'll automatically look for a boot loader at a predefined path on all partitions looking like EFI System Partitions. The bcdboot.exe and bcdedit.exe commands can also be used to restore it.

> PS Why is the E-drive partition set as "active"? I haven't done that. What's the use or function of that, of making a partition "active"? Background: This is a partition with a Win7 installation, which doesn't boot anymore after it was moved from back-of-disk to front-of-disk.

On BIOS systems, typically the disk-level MBR installed by an OS will look for an "Active" partition on that disk (and will jump to that partition's PBR/VBR for the next stage).

If the disk isn't being used for BIOS boot, then the flag on that disk's partitions has no effect.

(Even if the computer is booting in BIOS mode in general, the selected disk's MBR will only look for an "active" partition on the *same* disk – the flag still has no effect on non-boot disks.)

> This is a partition with a Win7 installation, which doesn't boot anymore after it was moved from back-of-disk to front-of-disk.

You can also repair this using bcdboot.

Comment: This is a great answer. I might checkmark it in 48 hours.  Still, a question: you said: "a pointer to a specific file within the "EFI System Partition" is stored in your motherboard's NVRAM as an "EFI variable". The system should still be able to boot without it, though – if the NVRAM boot entry is missing" Just for my understanding:  Is the **NVRAM boot entry** that file within the "EFI System Partition"? Or the pointer that is stored in the Mobo's NVRAM??

Comment: The motherboard's NVRAM stores the "boot entry" (which points to a specific partition GUID + file path), while the EFI System Partition stores the actual file (e.g. Bootmgfw.efi is the Windows Boot Manager).